# TensorFlow on Windows 10: “not a supported wheel on this platform” error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was following the [guide steps](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) until get the "not a supported wheel on this platform" error. I checked the Anaconda is properly installed with the following version information:

```
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  23 2016, 11:57:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's only available for Python 3.5.x not 3.6.

You can quickly create a 3.5 environment with `conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5`